# Overriding a virtual method with a generic return type

Tags: c#, generics

Consider these two abstract classes.  MyClass2 extends my BaseClass and overrides a virtual method.  Note it also defines TValue of MyBaseClass as IList...

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass<TKey, TValue>
{
    public virtual IList<TValue> DoSomeStuff()
    {
        IList<TValue> result;
        ....
        return restult;
    }
}

public abstract class MyClass2<TKey, TValue>: MyBaseClass<TKey, IList<TValue>>
{
    public override IList<TValue> DoSomeStuff()
    {
        IList<TValue> result;
        ....
        return restult;
    }
}
```

This code does not compile.  The complaint is on the return type of MyClass2.DoSomeStuff.  The error is "Cannot change return type when overriding method "`IList<TValue> MyClass2<TKey, TValue>.DoSomeStuff()`"

I'm not clear as to why this is wrong.  Why wouldn't the compile or .net consider TValue for the overriden method to be that of MyClass2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem's in your base class part:

```
public abstract class MyClass2<TKey, TValue>: MyBaseClass<TKey, IList<TValue>>
```

Replace the `IList<TValue>` with `TValue` and it will work - the method already returns an `IList`.

Answer (score 3):

The `TValue` parameter of your base class, as inherited by your subclass, is actually `IList<TValue>` as declared by your subclass. The inner `TValue` pertains to your subclass.

So if you're trying to override the existing virtual method that belongs to the base class, the return type is actually expected to be `IList<IList<TValue>>`; that is, an `IList` of the `TValue` that belongs to your base class, not the subclass.

Comment: hrmm..then i guess the only way to keep the type the same is to 'genericize' the method itself.  generics and inheritance seems to be rather trouble some.

Comment: @mike01010 From the limited code you showed, I would change the class to `MyClass2<TKey, TValue>: MyBaseClass<TKey, TValue>` instead if you want `DoSomeStuff` to still return `IList<TValue>`

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because `TValue` in the child class is actually `IList<TValue>` in the base class so the method signature (as your base class would see it) would be `IList<IList<TValue>>` which obviously doesn't match the virtual method's signature.

To get matching types, you would have to change the signature:

```
public override TValue DoSomeStuff()
{
    TValue result;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'd change the signature of the virtual method instead.

Comment: @BoltClock - That all depends on which one is actually wrong. I was assuming that the base class would have other children which may have completely different implementations. In that case, you would have to modify the child.

Comment: TKey and TValue are used for a Dictionary.  In some classes, the Dictionary stores single value in other a List (multimap).  so for example it might store {int, MyObject} or {int, IList<MyObject>}.  Im guessing i might be trying to have these classes do too much in this case.